# Want to understand the concept of ActionResult in MVC.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionresult

I am new to MVC development.

> I am trying to figure out about ActionResult.

I have go to many links on this forum itself... but I don't think anyone give clear answer...

I have read many answers like ViewResult is derived from ActionResult and 
Rendering thing...

but Boss, What exactly ActionResult is ?

We know the return types like string, double,int but what exactly ActionResult is ? 
What it returns ?

Can anyone tell me in simple manner ?

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulates the result of an action method and is used to perform a framework-level operation on behalf of the action method.

The Action Result in ASP.NET MVC provides a simple and versatile means of returning different types of response to the browser.

**It's an abstract class that returns following SubTypes**

- **ViewResult**
- **PartialViewResult**
- **EmptyResult**
- **RedirectResult**
- **RedirectToRouteResult**
- **JsonResult**
- **JavaScriptResult**
- **ContentResult**
- **FileContentResult**
- **FileStreamResult**
- **FilePathResult**

What do you want to return ?

View ? partial View ? Some Json String ? File response the client ?

Comment: I have gone through above details...want to know What exactly the Action result is ? means , In string type return we have some string like "testtesttest" , in double type return we have some "21233.23" return, so in action result , what it returns ?

Comment: You can envisage the ActionResult class as being a way to encapsulate the particular type(SubTypes above mentioned) of response that you want to send to the browser.

Comment: lets say I use ViewResult instead of ActionResult ? What wil be the difference...I want to know fundamentals of actionresult, which is no where mentioned...What is actionResult ???? String,Double,its in encrypted,its in html ?

Comment: ViewResult is an implementation for this abstract class. It will try to find a view page (usually aspx page) in some predefined paths(/views/controllername/, /views/shared/, etc) by the given view name. Like wise other sub types are implementation of this abstract class.

Comment: **lets say I use ViewResult instead of ActionResult** - This means now your return type is `ViewResult` and tomorrow your return types change to some other Sub Types let's say Json Result. If you keep the return type as Action Result, MVC will take care of all above sub types despite of the fact that you are returning JSON, Partial View or file anything. Basically, Action Result, returns different types of response to the browser.

Comment: ya, I want to know what kind of responses how are they differ ? how the ViewResult is different from ActionResult ?

Comment: **How the ViewResult is different from ActionResult ?** - ViewResult is a generic type and only returns View whereas Actionresult is a generic type returns all the sub types mentioned in the answer.

Comment: **ya, I want to know what kind of responses how are they differ ?** - All the above mentioned subtypes are responses. Rendering View/Partial View/JSON/File response to client all are responses to client.